# Make the format requirements more clear, especially the code format indentation part

Tags: support, feature-request, editor

The line indentation almost made me lose hope when I was trying to ask my question in the main platform of Stack Overflow, as it was hard to understand what was required of me. Perhaps, you guys could create an illustration of what's needed and how the code should be indented. This will largely help those who are learning to code and are not proficient in English.

> To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces:

```
        This will be displayed in a monospaced font. The first four spaces
        will be stripped off, but all other whitespace will be preserved.

        Markdown and HTML are turned off in code blocks:
        <i>This is not italic</i>, and [this is not a link](https://example.com)
```

The above message is not clear enough. A short video or an animation in a .gif format to illustrate what's needed will make a big difference.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I think they are saying the explanation of the code block is confusing.

Comment: What exactly isn't clear? Why is the explanation confusing?

Comment: Earlier, when I experienced a problems with my code , I copied and pasted my code in the body section of stack overflow website. To seek assistance.However, I could not post my whole question immediately, and i struggled to understand what was meant by code intent.  Firstly it was not clear why must the code be indent with 4 spaces and whether it was the whole code or just a portion of it which must be intended. This is just a suggestion that an animation must be added to illustrate how a code should be intended, so that dummies like me, will not have problems.

Comment: @Travolta if you believe you are not proficient in a language (whether computer one or spoken one) it is good idea to check meaning of words you don't understand. Generally google/bing search will do, dictionary may work too if you like books - https://www.bing.com/search?q=what%20is%20code%20intent and https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+is+code+indentation show that there is significant difference between "indent" and "intent" - good idea to know check out to limit confusion...

Answer (score 11):

The official [editing-help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) page does a much better job at visualizing this than [that Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193323/how-to-enter-code-snippets-in-posts-on-stack-overflow/193325#193325) where you presumably found that example (which is actually taken from an *old* version of that help page, and is poorly formatted to the extent of making the example useless).

The current version of that help page highlights the four spaces you need to add to each line for the code block formatting to kick in:

[image]

(The use of color probably doesn't make this very helpful to colorblind users, however... and that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> shortcut isn't the most intuitive either.)